# Как записать звук в конец wav файла в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mp3, wav, pyaudio

Предположим имеется wav файл в котором уже имеется звук, например, 5 секундная запись голоса, как дописать еще несколько секунд записи на Python, не перезаписывая файл полностью? т.е. добавить звук в файл.

Comment: А есть ли у вас наработки, попытки решения? Их можно добавить через [edit]

Comment: Наработок нет, хочу узнать может хоть кто то делал подобное